# How to set a "no data" value to use in Zonal Statistics?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics

I have a raster with the thickness of an aquifer confining unit and I'm using zonal statistics to calculate the average thickness under a buffer zone around well points. However, in areas where the confining unit isn't present, there is just no data rather than a 0 value.

How can I change this raster so that zonal statistics will include the area with no thickness data as a "0" datapoint?

Comment: I'm assuming because you want to perform a Zonal Statistics you have a spatial analyst license.. You can create a new raster with 0 replacing Null with a Con(IsNull(InRaster),0,InRaster) in arcpy or by the tools Con http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z00000005000000 and IsNull http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000m8000000. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Yep, I have spatial analyst... I'll try that!

Comment: When (and if) it works for you can you please answer your own question, with pictures, to help others who may have the same problem.. thanks. I personally find it easier to use Raster Calculator http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000z7000000 rather than Con itself. You can run Con from a Raster Calculator window, as well as many other spatial analyst tools, it's much more versatile.